# Is ServletContext one per web-app or one per JVM?

Tags: java, servlets

Here is the doubt I have come up with ServletContext is one per web-app and one per JVM. But if I am running more than one web-app on the same JVM. Then it has 2 ServletContext per JVM. Is it Possible? Can anybody elaborate on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each webapp will have its own ServletContext. The way the [api docs](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) put it is:

> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog  and possibly installed via a .war file.)

The "per web application" part means that if you set up the application in a cluster then each node in the cluster has a separate JVM, and that JVM will be running separate copies of all the applications, including a ServletContext for each webapp.

Answer (score 8):

One per web application and one per JVM can be explained with the following tables.

**Several Web Apps on one Server (one JVM):**

```
Web App A - Server/JVM 1 - Context 1 
Web App B - Server/JVM 1 - Context 2 
Web App C - Server/JVM 1 - Context 3
```

**Same Web App on several Servers (several JVMs):**

```
Web App A - Server/JVM 1 - Context 1 
Web App B - Server/JVM 1 - Context 2 
Web App C - Server/JVM 1 - Context 3 
Web App C - Server/JVM 2 - Context 4
```

Answer (score 3):

[ServletContext](http://ajava.org/online/java_ee_javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html):

> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.

That means each web application has exactly one `ServletContext` on each VM. (The multiple-VM case is when you have a distributed application)